# Get installed packages url using apt

Tags: apt, package-management

As you may know we can use `apt-get install --print-uris -y package-name` and it show us a list of URLs, hashsum, etc.

However if we use it for a package that already has been installed on system it does not work:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
package is already the newest version (x.x-x).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

So how can I get a list of necessary URLs using `apt` or other CLI tools like `aptitude`?

**PS:** *I Don't want to use [packages.ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com).*

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Not all installed packages will have a URL associated with them, of course. However, you could use `apt-get dowload`:

```
$ apt-get download --print-uris wget
'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/w/wget/wget_1.15-1ubuntu1.14.04.2_amd64.deb' wget_1.15-1ubuntu1.14.04.2_amd64.deb 270522 SHA256:a3f3b049ea373402236a804a5a0952c6ef9b356ba8cc19fbc1f257db6e8f3052
```

This is the candidate version as shown by `apt-cache policy`, which might not necessarily be the installed version.

Answer (score 7):

It seems to be sufficient to add the `--reinstall` flag (at least on my 16.04 system) e.g.

```
$ sudo apt-get install --print-uris wget
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
wget is already the newest version (1.17.1-1ubuntu1.2).
wget set to manually installed.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 73 not upgraded.
```

but

```
$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall --print-uris wget
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 73 not upgraded.
Need to get 298 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
'http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/w/wget/wget_1.17.1-1ubuntu1.2_amd64.deb' wget_1.17.1-1ubuntu1.2_amd64.deb 298270 MD5Sum:09a54f8d74c78598f91c4b376f3d2f0e
```

---

NOTE: this doesn't work if the package is currently cached:

```
$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall --download-only wget
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 73 not upgraded.
Need to get 298 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 wget amd64 1.17.1-1ubuntu1.2 [298 kB]
Fetched 298 kB in 0s (382 kB/s)
Download complete and in download only mode

$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall --print-uris wget
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 73 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/298 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
```

but after clearing the cache

```
$ sudo apt-get clean
$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall --print-uris wget
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 73 not upgraded.
Need to get 298 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
'http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/w/wget/wget_1.17.1-1ubuntu1.2_amd64.deb' wget_1.17.1-1ubuntu1.2_amd64.deb 298270 MD5Sum:09a54f8d74c78598f91c4b376f3d2f0e
```